# a problem on HDLBits: Design a 1-12 counter with the following inputs and outputs

Tags: verilog, hdl

Design a 1-12 counter with the following inputs and outputs:

Reset Synchronous active-high reset that forces the counter to 1
Enable Set high for the counter to run
Clk Positive edge-triggered clock input
Q[3:0] The output of the counter
c_enable, c_load, c_d[3:0] Control signals going to the provided 4-bit counter, so correct operation can be verified.
You have the following components available:

the 4-bit binary counter (count4) below, which has Enable and synchronous parallel-load inputs (load has higher priority than enable). The count4 module is provided to you. Instantiate it in your circuit.
logic gates

```
module count4(
    input clk,
    input enable,
    input load,
    input [3:0] d,
    output reg [3:0] Q
);

/here begin to code:
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input enable,
    output [3:0] Q,
    output c_enable,
    output c_load,
    output [3:0] c_d
); 

    count4 the_counter (clk, c_enable, c_load, c_d /*, ... */ );

endmodule
/here finish code
```

The problem is on the website(https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki/Exams/ece241_2014_q7a),I have tried to solve it but failed sadly, so could you give me a correct answer and tell me the reason, thanks a lot!

here is my failed code:

```
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input enable,
    output [3:0] Q,
    output c_enable,
    output c_load,
    output [3:0] c_d
); //
    assign c_enable = enable;
    assign c_d = 4'd1;
    assign c_load = (reset||(Q==4'd12)) ? 1 : 0;

    count4 the_counter (clk, c_enable, c_load, c_d, Q );

endmodule
```

Comment: *"...but failed"* is not very descriptive. What fails? Do you have an error  message? Or specify what you see and what you expected to see.

Comment: The simulation waveform is different from the standard answer given by the website.(Maybe I should use 'the simulation result is wrong' instead of 'failed')

Answer (score 0):

I notice a discrepancy. I don't know if that is you fault in copying the text or that the error is in the original assignment:

The signal `c_d` is an **output** in the test-bench (top_module) but is in input into the count4 module. That means that in the code above nobody is driving the signal.

Please be more precise when asking a question. *"The result is wrong"* is not helpful either. Best is to describe in text "I should see A at time B but instead at time C, D comes out".  In this case I would additionally show the waveforms side-by-side.